# Java EE: Is is it wise to make my context attribute thread-safe in this scenario?

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety, servlet-3.0

I'm implementing a dynamic notification system  (a la Facebook) for my website with the help of the Servlet 3.0 API. My planned structure to support this functionality is:

1. On each page load, send an XMLHTTP "get"
   request to the server
2. Allow the server to create AsyncContext objects
   from these "get" requests and store
   them in an application-scoped map 
   keyed by the user's website ID
3. Whenever a user engages in an action
   that spawns notification, query the
   application-scoped map for IDs of
   the user's friends, and using the
   AsyncContext objects stored there, send
   the notification to each friend.
4. Each of the friends receive the
   notification.

My question is: is it necessary to make this map thread-safe? In the worst case scenario, a function acting on behalf of the "notification-sending-user" would send the notification to a stale async-context in the map, either because the user is it corresponds to is currently switching pages and has yet to send a new XMLHTTP request, or has logged out.

On each page load however, I also have code to retrieve all notifications in the database newer than the "last checked date", so on page load, notifying the user doesn't rely on the dynamic notification system. So, the user will still get the notification if he is switching pages (and obviously the concept of notifications is not relevant if the user logged out).

Given this information, are there any scenarios that would require the map to be thread safe?

Answer (score 2):

You might not need exact consistency.. but you still don't want ANY threads reading to a normal hashmap while it is being written to (an add could cause a rehash and put the getting thread in an infinite loop).

Also, this plan won't scale super well past 1 server. If that is OK.... just use a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Can you explain why it won't scale past 1 server using ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: It won't scale past 1 server to store everything in a hashmap. You would want to store this in a database and do something or other fancy....

Comment: Another question/remark. Context-scoped attributes can't be updated while *in* the context; they can only be set or retrieved. ConcurrentHashMap won't be necessary here since each user will retrieve a copy of the map in order to read/insert data, then put it back in to the context under the same key. So the question is whether I would need a lock over the context; I phrased the original question incorrectly. Would you mind answering my updated question?